# Using Parallel.ForEach with List throws AggregateException

Tags: c#, list, exception, aggregate, parallel.foreach

**Windows Forms Application:**
I got a list with objects and want to call a function for each object in this list. Each function should be done within a thread. Only 3 threads should be max active at the same time. When one thread has been finished, the next thread should start until all objects in list are processed.

I tried to use a `Parallel.ForEach`, but got AggregateException(s). Can you please tell me why the exception is thrown?

List with my objects: `ZuInstallierendeAssetsList` >> `List<vw_AC_FilteredPrinters2> ZuInstallierendeAssetsList`

Here is my code:

```
        var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };
        int index = 0;

        var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();

        Parallel.ForEach(ZuInstallierendeAssetsList, options,
                (OneObject) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        index++;                    
                        test(OneObject.FIRSTNAME, index);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { exceptions.Enqueue(ex); }
                });

        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
```

Here is the function to call:

```
private void test (string _prt, int _index)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.listBox_Console.Items.Add("DataInObject:" + _prt + ", " + _index);
        }
```

Some objects of the list are processed, depends on the time the function takes to execute. When i use the `Thread.Sleep`, there will be processed 2 objects from the list before the exception is thrown. Without the `Thread.Sleep`, there will be 12 objects processed before exception is thrown. The list contains about 500 objects.

Comment: An aggregate exception is a list of exceptions. Could you please add what those exceptions are and the messages they give?

Comment: An AggregateException is usually thrown when multiple threads are executing and at least one of them threw an exception. All thrown exceptions are then collected inside an AggregatException and that exception is then kicked in your face. To help you we need to know what kinds of exceptions you find inside the `InnerExceptions` property of your AggregateException.

Comment: Now i changed the catch to this code and i got an exception which helps me...
                `catch (AggregateException ae)
                {
                    foreach (Exception ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }`

Problem seems to happen cause the code wants to add a new listbox item to the listbox and cannot reach the gui from the thread. 
I think i have to invoke in order to write into the listbox. Can you please tell me best practice to do?